# Getting classNotFindException when using Firebase performance lib with slyce android sdk

Tags: android, firebase-performance

I am currently stuck with integrating the new firebase perf with my current android app. Everything works fine when I disable it i.e., `firebasePerformanceInstrumentationEnabled = false. But I keep getting the below error when I enable it i.e., set it's value to` true`.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    Process: com.testflight.app, PID: 22011

    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/neovisionaries/ws/client/D;

        at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketFactory.<init>(SourceFile:2)

        at it.slyce.sdk.internal.SlyceWebSocketWorkflowTask.e(SourceFile:1)

        at it.slyce.sdk.internal.SlyceWebSocketWorkflowTask.onEncodingComplete(SourceFile:3)

        at it.slyce.sdk.internal.BitmapEncodingTask.a(SourceFile:4)

        at it.slyce.sdk.internal.BitmapEncodingTask.onPostExecute(SourceFile:1)

        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:755)

        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:192)

        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:772)

        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)

        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)

        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7811)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)

        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)

     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.neovisionaries.ws.client.D" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ashleyfurniturehomestore.ecomm-X1w1G27mqcSRlwfLujt7mQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.testflight.app-X1w1G27mqcSRlwfLujt7mQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.testflight.app-X1w1G27mqcSRlwfLujt7mQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]

        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)

        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)

        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)

        at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketFactory.<init>(SourceFile:2) 

        at it.slyce.sdk.internal.SlyceWebSocketWorkflowTask.e(SourceFile:1) 

        at it.slyce.sdk.internal.SlyceWebSocketWorkflowTask.onEncodingComplete(SourceFile:3) 

        at it.slyce.sdk.internal.BitmapEncodingTask.a(SourceFile:4) 

        at it.slyce.sdk.internal.BitmapEncodingTask.onPostExecute(SourceFile:1) 

        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:755) 

        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:192) 

        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:772) 

        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 

        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 

        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7811) 

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 

        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 

        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run with proguard disabled. If it works, you need to edit your ProguardRules.pro file to exclude Firebase libraries.

Comment: Tried that, it's still same.